# Abort mstest test from TestInitialize

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mstest

I'm trying to Abort/Stop/Cancel test run from TestInitialize.
What I'm trying is to check if test method has custom attribute and if so ,abort the test.
TestContext doesn't have this ability ,
Is there any solutions to abort test using code?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stop the test run, you can call Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill() or Environment.Exit. This will stop the current process (where the tests are running).

If you want to stop only the test which is about to run. You not group your tests so that only the relevant tests are executed:

[How to: Group and Run Automated Tests Using Test Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286683.aspx)